# Pine Script: Plotting Shapes with variable offsets

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to mark various historical candles using the `plotshape()` function. 
It looks like this, 
`plotshape(plot_pivot, "Pivot",  shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny, color=color.blue, offset=pivot_offset)`

Problem is, 
`pivot_offset` keeps changing depending upon where the pivot has been found.
However, as soon as the `pivot_offset` changes, *ALL* the previously marked pivots shift places.
I have realized that the `offset` parameter of the `plotshape` function shifts the *entire series* every time it gets a new value.

Question,
Is there a way to work around this problem?
I don't want all the previously marked pivots to shift, only the most recent one.

I know I can use labels here, but they have a limitation of max 500 on a chart.
Hence, I don't want to use labels.
I also looked at `barcolor`, but it has the same offset problem.

Comment: Why do you need an offset? Couldn't you just use `plotshape()` on the bar it occurs on? I usually use `bgcolor()` to mark historical bars, and I do it on the bar that the condition occurs on. `bgcolor()` will also have the offset problem you're describing, when you're using offset.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen Not possible in my case. It's somewhat like looking back 15 bars at the lowest bar _after_ a moving average crossover occurs and marking that bar. The lowest bar will always be at a different offset from the bar where the MA crossover has taken place.
I am making do with the Labels at the moment, of course there's a 500 limit to them, would have been great if there was a way to mark every occurence on the chart.